# Error While Running update-manager

Tags: python, update-manager, python3

I am getting the below error while trying to run `update-manager` in my Ubuntu 16.04. Looks like it is trying to run `python3` instead of `python2.7`.

Running `sudo update-manager` gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/update-manager", line 28, in <module>
    from gi.repository import Gtk
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 39
    print url
            ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
```

Comment: DId you change the symlink for your system Python to point to Python 3?

Comment: I am not sure what is symlink

Comment: no python runs python 2.7.12 version